# Python Type Hints: может ли указать динамический возвращаемый тип для подклассов?

Tags: python, ооп, python-3.x

Сделал адаптер. Адаптер принимает какой-то класс, и возвращает себя.

```
class Adapter(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, adaptable_object):
        self._adaptable_object = adaptable_object

   @property
   def adaptable_object(self) -> Adapter:  # Этот метод приходится перегружать
        return self.adaptable_object


class B(Adapter):

    @property
    def adaptable_object(self) -> "B":  # Типа перегрузил.
        return super().adaptable_object
```

Есть ли возможность указать как тип возвращаемого объекта сам вызывающий класс?

Или может какое есть другое решение, чтобы не перегружать метод в каждом новом наследнике?

Comment: Если `adaptable_object()` это тип конструктора, который обязан именно подкласс экземпляр вернуть, а не просто переменную базового класса, то вы можете попробовать [generic self](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self): `TypeVar('T', bound='Adatpter')` вместо Adapter. В общем случае относитесь с подозрением к случаям, когда вы используете наследование, но не можете использовать конкретную переменную как экземпляр базового класса—если вы пытаетесь конкретный подкласс из базового метода вытянуть, может следует рассмотреть делегирование в таком случае

Comment: Не знаю как вы догадались, но в оригинальном варианте действительно реализовал паралельный конструктор, а здесь немного не то написал, но видимо уровень телепатии у вас очень высокий :-)

Comment: Короче я адаптировал через `@classmethod`, а создавал через `__init__`, мне изначально показалось, что так будет более близко к питону, но возникло много неудобств. В итоге стал адаптировать через `__init__`, а создавать новые экземпляры через `@classmethod`, и проблемки такого рода отвалились, да и кода стало меньше.

Comment: Да, использование @сlassmethod для альтернативных конструкторов является идиоматичным, к примеру: datetime.now, datetime.fromtimestamp являются classmethod (при наследовании возвращаются экземпляры подклассов, а не базового класса такими методами)

Answer (score -1):

Описание типа возвращаемого объекта ни на что не влияет, оно используется только для статического анализа кода сторонними средствами или для подсказок в IDE.

Comment: Ясен пень. Для этого и нужно.